# "Reserved SQL words are written in uppercase" or "reserved SQL words are written in uppercase letters"?

Tags: word-choice

> Reserved SQL words are written in uppercase.
>   Reserved SQL words are written in uppercase letters.

Would the first sentence be understood? Would the second sentence be preferable, or more correct?

Comment: "Would the first sentence understood?" Everyone knows what you mean, but that sentence cries out for a verb.

Comment: @moioci: Fixed.

Comment: I also noticed that I wrote _upper case_, instead of _uppercase_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think both of these would be equally understandable and well-formed, although in the context of SQL and programming, I think the idea of *uppercase* and *lowercase* is common enough that the first example would be slightly preferred.  But nobody would ever find it strange to see your second example.

Comment: I'd disagree. In programming, I never see the term "uppercase _letters_ "; it's a given that they are letters!

Comment: Random examples of the phrase "uppercase letters" being used when talking about programming:
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22uppercase+letters%22+php

Answer (score 3):

I think both sentences say the same thing, the former with fewer words, and so I'd prefer that.

Also, most books that I've read tend to state the language first, such as "C++ reserved words" or "Reserved words in SQL".  "Reserved SQL words" sounds awkward to me, although I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute. Isn't it "upper case" when used as a noun and "uppercase" when used as an adjective? Or am I incorrect in my hypercorrectness?

Comment: The dictionary says it is one word as a noun and adjective: http://mw1.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uppercase?show=1&t=1285534985.

Comment: @Kos Hmm, thanks. I guess I could have looked it up myself, eh? Didn't mean to be lazy. So then is "upper case" incorrect?

Comment: I imagine it is a valid variant, although I don't (anecdotally) see it much.